# How to send array to java (android) only with hotspot connection?

Tags: java, javascript, android

first off all sorry about the non-smooth english.
I have a problem with get data from user to my database or to string in my android java code.

I created website until now and i'm using my mobile as server.

In order to connect this site i turn the hotspot on and from a pc or other device i wrote the ip address with the port in the browser's address bar. for example, 192.160.42.1:8081.

My problem is that i have contact form in the site and i need the user will fill his details then i will get it in the android code (when he clicks send).

So can the user in the web click "send" and i will have a script that creates a new record in my Sqlite database? It will work for IE,Chrome,FireFox,Safary and android tablets browser? or i can pass string with his details from the contact form? (from the javascript to the java).
Notice that i dont have internet connection except the hotspot.

Answer (score 0):

Bit unsure at what you are asking but if you just want to store the data locally then use an sqlite database from within your application, if you want to send data to an external website then in your code check for a internet connection and send a json string to your website and let a script there handle whatever you want to do with the data. If you dont have an internet connection then you could store the data in a sqlite database and send it when there is an connection.

Comment: The only connection is the hotspot. When its on (the hotspot) the user can enter to my local site (my tablet is the server for this site). When the user click send to send his details i would never have an Internet connection. Can i update my sqlite database that i created in my android app, from the javascript and it will works for the browsers i wrote above??